# Modeling nearest event through multivariate random variable with condition

Tags: distributions, probability, modeling

There are two time sequences in my system, one of them represents IN events, and the other OUT events. Each IN event would be released by the nearest following OUT event or reaching the deadline. I want to get the pdf of the interval between the time the IN event is triggered until the time it is released (OUT event occurs or censored at deadline).

As the following figure shows, $t_a$, $t_r$, $t_r^'$ represent the IN event time, the nearest OUT event time and last OUT event time prior to $t_r$. The nearest OUT event can be represented as $t_r>t_a$ and $t_r^' < t_a$. I extend the situation to statistics, so that $t_a$ is a sample of random variable $T_a \sim U(0,T)$. $t_r$ obey $T_r \sim U(0,2T)$. The interval of two OUT event, $t_r-t_r^'$, should be treated as $T_i \sim Exp(\lambda)$.

[image]

How to model this complex multivariate random variable and get its pdf?

Furthermore, deadline of event $t_a$ is $2T$, which means that if there is no $t_r$ between $(t_a, 2T)$, it would be released at time $2T$. This condition could introduce more difficulty of modeling.

Comment: I have done some editing of your question but did not change any of the inequalities you gave.  However, shouldn't t$_a$ be < t'$_r$ so that t$_r$ can be less than t'$_r$ as it needs to be by the definition of t'$_r$?

Comment: The figure shows the relationship of the events. $t_a$ must $ > t_r^'$ to ensure that $t_r$ is the nearest following OUT event. If $t_a > t_r^'$ satisfied, than $t_r^'$ would be the nearest following event. Pay attention to that $t_r^'$ is the latest OUT event before $t_r$.  @MichaelChernick

Comment: The reason for my confusion is that you called t'$_r$ "the last OUT event".  So I interpreted it to mean the last OUT event of all OUT events.  Seems that what you meant to say is 'the last OUT event prior to t$_a$'.  Am I correct?  In that case the inequalities you gave make sense.  I think if that is the case you really should define it as "the last OUT event prior to t$_a$.

Comment: Actually, as I has edited, $t_r^'$ should be defined as "the last OUT event prior to $t_r$." It means there is no other OUT event between $t_r^'$ and $t_r$. @MichaelChernick

Comment: Okay Thanks for the edit.  I will see if i can answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have defined the model based on the defined times to events in your question. You have two point processes with censoring times.  The time to events [IN events and OUT events] is defined in your post.
2. The time 2T just amounts to a censoring time which is handled routinely in survival analysis if you just assume the OUT event occurs beyond 2T but since you are assuming the OUT event does occur at 2T if not before that amounts to truncating its distribution.
3. Since the time between out events is exponential the lack of memory property says that given the in event occurs at time t$_a$ does not change the distribution of the time to the next event. So the time from t$_a$ to the next OUT event is still exp(λ).  But given that the out event is truncated at time 2T the actual distribution that you want is 
   V = min(t$_1$, t$_2$) where t$_1$ is distributed

exp(λ) and t$_2$=2T-t$_a$.  This just makes the probability

given t$_a$ that V=2T-t$_a$ is the probability that an exp(λ) random variable E is greater

than 2T-t$_a$. and it follows the exp(λ) density when

0 < E < 2T-t$_a$.

Comment: The pdf is still unknown. Should this model be described as mixed discrete-continuous distribution?

Comment: It is continuous unless you put OUT events beyond as though they occurred at 2T.  Then it would be a mixed discrete and continuous with point mass at 2T for P(E>=2T).  But you don't have to approach it that way.